# MySQL multiple tables to refer same foreign key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have three tables like this.

```
location(id,name)

tour(id,name)

hotel(id,name)
```

above three tables(location, tour and hotel) has many images.

So the traditional way to store the images would be

```
location_images(id,image_url,location_id)

tour_images(id,image_url,tour_id)

hotel_images(id,image_url,hotel_id)
```

Instead of keeping images in three different tables like this can I make  one table for store all three types of images like this?

```
images(id,image_url,type,foreign_key)
```

How do I achieve this using MySQL?

How do I make my `foreign_key` connect with the `type`?

I am using MySQL `5.7.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 (Ubuntu)`

Comment: You can keep `type` and `type_id` as composite foreign key in image table,

Comment: I think we don't need to defined type and type_id as primary key but can fetch related records using `select * from images where image_type ='hotel' and image_id= 'hotel_id'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you represent inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579079/how-can-you-represent-inheritance-in-a-database)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

```
CREATE TABLE images (
id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
image_url VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
image_belongs_to_type ENUM('location', 'tour', 'hotel') NOT NULL,
post_id INT NOT NULL);
```

when you call the image just provide the post `ID` with `ENUM` value.
(location, tour and hotel)

eg :

```
select * from images where image_belongs_to_type ='location' and post_id = 'location_id'
select * from images where image_belongs_to_type ='tour' and post_id = 'tour_id'
select * from images where image_belongs_to_type ='hotel' and post_id = 'hotel_id'
```

[ENUM - MySql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html)